# Questions with ignored tags are a little too transparent

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, design, ignored-tags

The questions tagged with ignored tags have `opacity: 0.2` in the stylesheet. I think this is a little *too* transparent. Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow (the only two I checked) use `opacity: 0.5`.

If the user doesn't choose to hide ignored questions completely, then he should be able to read them. For me, anything below about 0.35 looks too transparent.

Comment: agreed. will fix soon.

Comment: 0.3 seems OK for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decreased the transparency slightly to 0.35. The change will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I like it being more transparent.  It makes them very easy to ignore.  I can still read them if I want to.

Comment: Actually I would rather say they are not transparent enough... so I even checked the "don't display at all" thingy.